# SQL Azure - Finding all dependencies on a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I recently had an issue whereby a datatype of column in a SQL Azure table was changed. This column had a number of views dependent on it. These views were also references by other databases using external tables. As you can image, the knock on impact was reasonably large. I am trying to amend the change control process to implement a direct check for these types of dependencies.

I have found queries like:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(referencing_id) ReferencingObject, OBJECT_NAME(referenced_id) ReferencedObject, * FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies
```

And

```
SELECT * FROM sys.external_data_sources
```

Now, I could write an app that the user can use to iterate over all databases, tables etc ... and find potential dependencies.
However, I'm wondering if there is a simpler query I can use.

Any advice?
Chris

Comment: A simpler solution would be to define all views and other objects using `WITH SCHEMABINDING`.

Comment: You should use database projects ([SSDT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver15)) and have this manage your deployments and state. It will validate stuff like that for you!

Comment: I can't use SSDT as the actual projects are database first and the databases are brought in a built upon.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to WITH SCHEMABINDING however we have found issues with that on SQL Azure and it doesn't help us with database we don't have control over.